# array_push not working within function, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-push

I have this case when I have array_push inside function and then I need to run it inside foreach filling the new array. Unfortunately I can't see why this does not work. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$mylist = array('house', 'apple', 'key', 'car');
$mailarray = array();

foreach ($mylist as $key) {
    online($key, $mailarray);
}

function online($thekey, $mailarray) {

    array_push($mailarray,$thekey);

}

print_r($mailarray);

?>
```

This is a sample function, it has more functionality and that´s why I need to maintain the idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PHP treats arrays as a sort of “value type” by default (copy on write). You can pass it by reference:

```
function online($thekey, &$mailarray) {
    $mailarray[] = $thekey;
}
```

See also [the signature of `array_push`](https://www.php.net/array_push).

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I would never be able to resolve that.

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass the array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php).

```
function online($thekey, &$mailarray) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I find it hard to accept the answer as you both posted at the same time! I just want to say thank you very much!!! @minitech